# In which cases mongoose does not generate its own id?

Tags: mongoose, backend

I'll simplify the code to focus on what I need to know

Let's say we have a schema, a model:

```
//imports....

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({name: String});
const model = mongoose.Model('Thing',schema);
```

and a method to create new documents from this model

```
async createDocFromBody(body){
  //... previous logic      

  await model.create(body);
  //....further steps

}
```

What I DO know is:

1. if body contains an "_id" field, mongoose will use its value to create the document id, and if not, it will create its own
2. if you try to cast a wrong type it will fail, so you must provide proper types when creating (in this case mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId)

What I do NOT know is:

let's say my body contains an '_id' key, but:
case 1:

```
  {_id:null, ...}
```

case 2:

```
  {_id:undefined, ...}
```

What happens then ?
Does mongoose ignores the values and creates its own "_id",  or tries to cast (and fails of course) to ObjectId ?

Comment: Try it out and let me know.

Comment: @RobertMoskal for case 2, mongoose ignores field and sets its own id. At least on my request it did .